# Add checkbox value to multiple fields in database

Tags: php, database, checkbox

I have a checkbox that if checked stores the value "testing" to the field "checkbox" om my database.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="testing">
```

I would like to store two values, on two fields on my database, from one checkbox.

If checked:
store value **testing**  to the *checkbox* field
store value **testing2** to the *checkbox2* field

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Can you provide any context and make question more specific (If you want more specific answer)?

Comment: this should probably be a `javascript` question, you could try using `onclick` to dynamically check the second checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" <?php if($val=="testing"): echo "value='testing'&nbsp; echo checked='on'" ?>">

  <input type="checkbox2" name="checkbox2" <?php if($val=="testing2"): echo "value='testing2'&nbsp; echo checked='on'" ?>">
```

Hope this is what you are looking for..

Comment: How does this relate to "on two fields on my database, from ONE checkbox" ? Really weird Q&A.